# No delay with settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a little script and am curious as to why the console logs all of the values immediately versus delaying the output until the timeouts are satisfied...

JS:

```
var test_obj = {
    init: function(i) {
        if (i < 10000) {
            console.log(i + "<br />");
            i = i+i;
            setTimeout(test_obj.init(i), i);
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    test_obj.init(i);
});
```

Comment: Since `test_obj.init(i)` returns `undefined`, therefore, what `setTimeout(test_obj.init(i), i);` really is, is  `setTimeout(false, i);`. Note that `test_obj.init` is executed before `setTimeout`, and you are supposed to pass the reference to the function instead of the result of the function. This is a common mistake JS beginners usually makes. :)

Comment: You can use ecmascript bind if you don't want to use anonymous function reference.

Comment: Does this mean that whenever I use parenthesis the script will always execute immediately?

Comment: When you use parens after the function call. It will invoke the function. What you need to provide `setTimeout` is the reference to the function(not invoking it there itself) so that it can invoke it when it needs to. That is where it failed in your case.

Comment: @tom c - http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/hAM2C/ This explains it all. (briefly) Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yeah nice demonstration...

Comment: Thanks for the example! I'm not sure I entirely understand why the return function only executes on the timeout... Also, what is the purpose of returning a function? What would happen if you simply return the alert("This will be inside setTimeout");?

Comment: @Tom C - http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/57wyH/ See this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because, you are not passing the function reference to the timeout. instead invoking it immediately by invoking it using parens `()`. `setTimeout(test_obj.init(i), i);` now, this will invoke the function and set the return value of the function as the reference which here is undefined as you don't return anything.

Instead try this way:

```
 init: function(i) {
        if (i < 10000) {
            console.log(i + "<br />");
            i = i+i;
            setTimeout(function(){ // Do this way
                 test_obj.init(i); 
             }, i);
        }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfFMb/)**

Another way you can do this is using **[function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**.

```
  setTimeout(test_obj.init.bind(this, i), i);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2D55/)**

Answer (score 3):

Because you are calling the function. You should pass a function pointer to setTimeout and not execute the function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    test_obj.init(i)
}, i);
```