# setInterval doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the functions I use to run a function periodically. I use the function to change the background of the body. but it doesn't get fired for some reason. Please help me with this code.

```
setInterval(uiImageChanger(),1);

    function uiImageChanger(){
        var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
        var images = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg'];

        if( currentTime > 00 && currentTime <= 12){
            $('body').css('background-image', "url(" + randomImagePicker(images ,'breakfast') + ")");
        }else if( currentTime > 12 && currentTime <= 16){
            $('body').css('background-image', "url(" + randomImagePicker(images ,'lunch') + ")");
        }else if( currentTime > 16 && currentTime <= 00){
            $('body').css('background-image', "url(" + randomImagePicker(images ,'dinner') + ")");
        }
    }

    function randomImagePicker(imgArray,time){
        if(time == 'breakfast'){
            return "../images/main_image/breakfast/" + imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)];
        }else if(time == 'lunch'){
            return "../images/main_image/lunch/" + imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)];
        }else if(time == 'dinner'){
            return "../images/main_image/dinner/" + imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)];
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481429/no-delay-with-settimeout/17481463#17481463 :)

Comment: Note that 1 in the second argument is 1 millisecond for 1 sec you need to mention 1000

Comment: yeah I figured that out! :) thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove parens from the setInterval function argument. Now, this will invoke the function and set the return value of the function as the reference to setInterval which here is `undefined` as you don't return anything. So basically you are setting interval on nothing, so nothing happens except the first execution while setting up the setInterval.

Change

```
setInterval(uiImageChanger(),1); // This will invoke the function immediately.
```

to

```
setInterval(uiImageChanger,1); // You want to set the reference of the function to setInterval.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass a pointer to a function and not execute the function.

```
setInterval(uiImageChanger,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of defining the function to be executed using setInterval.
One of the method is using the function reference for which the example is given by #mohkhan.
However you can do the following as well

```
    setInterval(function(){
           // code comes here.
    }, time_in_mills);
```

Also I see that you have mentioned the value for the function execution as 1. This means every 1 millisecond the function will be executed, which is not a good practice at all. Give a realistic time in millisecond so that you have given sufficient time for the code to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten several answers about the `setInterval()` problem. I'd like to point out a couple of other problems in the code.

First, this test will always fail:

```
else if( currentTime > 16 && currentTime <= 00)
```

After all, if a number is > 16 it cannot also be <= 0.

Also, you may get a warning about `00` being an octal constant which is deprecated. Of course, octal zero is the same value as decimal zero, but watch out for inadvertent octal constants: avoid using a leading zero.

And there is a lot of repetition in the code. You can easily remove all of this repetition to make the code more maintainable. Consider this approach:

```
// Return a random integer >= 0 and < n
function randomInt( n ) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * n );
}

// Return a random element from an array
function randomElement( array ) {
    return array[ randomInt(array.length) ];
}

function uiImageChanger(){
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    var meal =
        hour <= 12 ? 'breakfast' :
        hour <= 16 ? 'lunch' :
        'dinner';
    var images = [ 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg' ];
    $('body').css(
        'background-image',
        'url(../images/main_image/' + meal +
            '/' + randomElement(images) + ')'
    );
}
```